# Why can't I review a suggested edit which popped up in the review queue?

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

Occasionally I get items in the suggested edit queue which I can not review. Instead of the controls to approve/reject, I just see

> You are not able to review this item.

I just got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30657668) (screenshot below) item to review and it looks a lot like an audit.

- Why does StackOverflow suggest reviews I can't do? Is it a bug?
- It feels very frustrating to not be told **why** I can't review. Maybe the error message could be more descriptive?

As pointed out by Nick, this bug has already been [posted more than 4 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351175/what-are-these-this-item-is-not-reviewable-audits). Maybe its time to fix it?

Screenshot of linked example:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is an [old bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351175/what-are-these-this-item-is-not-reviewable-audits)

Comment: @RobertLongson No. Now I get "This item is no longer reviewable."

Comment: @Nick ah, didn't find anything. So its a bug thats at least 4 years old..

Comment: @Neuron *"Now I get "This item is no longer reviewable.""* - Yes, that's the message that you get if you navigate back to an audit after having left the page, for example if you were to skip an audit and go back to it. The *"You are not able to review this item."* is the message that I previously reported... yes, 4+ years ago.

Comment: @Nick yes, it was a reply to RobertLongson who said they could do the review. They reviewed it and asked me if I can review it now. Seems like they deleted their comment in the meantime. I don't know why

Comment: Perhaps changing the text to something a bit less black-boxish, like "This review has expired." Or "This review has been cleared."

Comment: When will it finally be (effectively) addressed?   _... I've experienced it on few occasions over the years; at times, the rate of occurrence is alarming._