# What causes a review task to become unavailable to a specific user?

Tags: support, review

Sometimes, review tasks are not reviewable to specific users, but are reviewable to others. Sometimes I am not offered review tasks and if I track them down manually I see:

> You are not able to review this item.

The examples that come to mind are:

- You cannot review edits you suggested or posts you own.
- You cannot review Suggested Edits audits you already viewed. Refreshing the page makes you no longer able to pass/fail a specific audit, but I have observed this on Suggested Edits only.
- You cannot review close/reopen votes that you already have a pending vote on.
- You found a direct link to a pending tag wiki edit, but you do not have the [approve tag wiki edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege.
- Presumably (though I have not observed this) you will not be able to review a close or reopen vote on a post that you have previously participated in closing or reopening respectively, because you cannot cast a vote twice unless your vote aged away.

However, sometimes seemingly arbitrarily, I will find a question with active close/reopen votes but there is no queue item available. I track down the item by looking at recent reviewers and their recent reviews, and I see that I am not able to review the item, even if I am eligible to cast a close/reopen vote outside of the queue. What types of interaction with the post could cause this?

What are **all** the conditions that would cause a certain review item to become ineligible to certain users? I am looking for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: FYI, this [answer](/a/362409) of [Clarify "This item is not reviewable" message](/q/163558) mentions two situations where a different message is shown instead.

Comment: [Almost dupe](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374482/why-cant-i-review-a-suggested-edit-which-popped-up-in-the-review-queue), but asking only about suggested edits, so leaving open. (Also different because the item did appear in the queue)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry That is totally a Suggested Edits audit.

Comment: Maybe but still doesn't explain why OP couldn't review it.

Comment: Note: I have found the [type of answer I am looking for](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581/1377755) but that explains why a task would become completed/invalidated and no longer reviewable to anyone, but I am looking for all the reasons that would cause a task to become not reviewable to **a specific user** but not others.